# Will my 555 timer circuit work the way I want it to?

Tags: relay, safety, 555, npn

Essentially, I am trying to implement a safety system for another project of mine. I am running a very high current through a rather large solenoid and want to ensure that a failure in its control circuitry does not result in a hot and dangerous mess.

I decided to use a 555 timer in its monostable configuration, after scouring the internet for a while I found a circuit that would output a set pulse length, regardless of the trigger length. (Ie. if the trigger length is longer than the output, the output will not be held high for the duration of the trigger, and if the trigger length is shorter than the output, the output will stay high for the duration of the set output length.)

The trigger is just a pushbutton, and the desired output length is around 1 second, (This is just over the time it takes for the solenoid do complete its function). The output goes to a 150R resistor then the base of a Bc337 NPN transistor, which switches the relays for the power to the solenoids circuitry. Although one relay is shown, I plan to implement one for the overall circuit power and one directly switching the power to the solenoid. The relays are 893-896H1CHD00112VDC, automotive relays from Mouser.

Long story short, will my circuit maintain its output length for all durations of the input length (within reason, the button will not be held for minutes on end).

**More Info**

The original circuit activated a solenoid on the button press and pushed a metal rod into a furnace for melting. After having the issue where the button was left on, completely melting said solenoid, I felt it important to add a safety circuit. A sensor was added to ensure that the circuit only ever worked while a rod securely seated in position. The 555 timer as intended to activate the solenoid for just enough time for the rod to be injected, while ensuring it was fully injected. The short pulse length sent from the 555 would also prevent a sensor or circuit failure from keeping the solenoid on, thus preventing another solenoid meltdown.

The idea for the circuit was to simply cut the power using the relay, so that when the button was pressed and the sensor was being triggered the solenoid would activate. The sensor circuit is very simple, and by cutting the power I could control all the solenoids at once without much difficulty, while also being able to add more solenoids in the future.

As the device will be in a rather dirty and hot workshop, the main failure states of concern would be; a blocked sensor, a false trigger (accidental press), components overheating/melting, the rods getting stuck, etc. I assume my 555 timer circuit will solve most issues as the solenoids would never be on for long enough to cause damage, allowing us to fix/unblock issues without the risk of catastrophic failure while allowing workflow to continue.

**Note:**

- Only one relay needs to be rated for a high current but I have multiple already on hand
- The solenoids circuit used to be triggered by a button and is now triggered via a sensor, so the additional circuitry isn't an inconvenience
- I need to be able to re-trigger the timer after the output pulse has ended
- The specs of the NPN and the relay in the diagram are not correct
- The relays already have a diode built in

This is what I decided on:

[image]

All suggestions welcome, including complete redesigns if they would be a significant improvement. (preferably without a microcontroller)

Comment: hm, this is quite a complex circuit with many sources of failure. How complex is the system this is protecting against failure? How likely is *that* to fail in the first place? Also, the NE555: probably not my first choice for a watchdog. ANd you want to design plenty of reverse- and overvoltage protection, otherwise a flyback spike from your solenoid (which is quite likely) will kill your safeguard pretty early.

Comment: I do agree, by the way, a complex software-based solution with a microcontroller is often an undesirable safeguard, as it introduces many new modes of failure itself, but looking at this: Are you sure it would be any less reliable?

Comment: Do you want your pushbutton to increase the length of solenoid activation when pressed again while solenoid is still on?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Sorry I should have been more specific, the system it is protecting is rather simple and already has a Schottky diode across the solenoid, and the 12v it is receiving from the supply of the original circuit is already regulated. The original circuit is fairly robust and unlikely to fail however, should it occur, it would be costly and catastrophic as the solenoids are both carrying a high current and custom.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, The reason this circuit was supposed to be easy to integrate is that the original circuit was designed to be modular. I have nothing against microcontrollers but I already have most of these components on hand and won't need to adjust it any time soon so I thought it would be simpler and easier. It would be nice if it didn't increase the length of the circuit's activation, however, it's main intention is to prevent failure by ensuring that the circuit is never on for long enough to cause damage, say if the sensor got blocked and thus the solenoid was left powered.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Also this circuit does not control the solenoid directly, only the power to it, and its control circuitry. The high current and potential spikes from the solenoid should already be separate.

Comment: that sounds like your desired functionality is "WHILE button is pressed AND solenoid not on for longer than x seconds, THEN solenoid is ON", is that right?

Comment: Couldn’t you use a slow blow fuse and short circuit all that complexity? For example, the lack of a flyback diode will cause the transistor to avalanche and probably eventually fail “on”, removing all “protection “. The relay contacts are presumably carrying high current and could weld etc.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Well sort of, keep in mind me pressing the button doesn't do much unless the conditions of the first circuit are already met, it is only supposed to be a safety, and at the moment I am happy with the precautions in place, I am just curious about the actual functionality of the circuit itself. Is a flyback better/more important than a schottky

Comment: This entire circuit is trying to prevent a catastrophic fail state, the functioning of the circuit surrounding the solenoid has already been tested and approved, it is not necessary, but given the high power, it would give me peace of mind

Comment: Pizzashape, I'm still trying to fully understand what the circuit needs to actually do, as your description, especially with respect to activation, is ambiguous, and now, with the button not actually being the activator, I'm not sure what still makes sense, at all :(

Comment: seriously, I'd say instead of simplifying the problem in a way that your readers can't understand, maybe start with fully describing it in your question – with where what activation comes from, what the failure to stop actually means, and so on, and then propose a simplification.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Fair Enough. The original circuit activated the solenoid on the button press and pushed a metal rod into a furnace for melting. After having the issue where the button was left on, completly melting said solenoid, i felt it important to add a safety circuit. (When I mentioned that it was a modular circuit, it meant that more solenoids (Injectors) could be added without the need for a re design). Thus the idea for the 555 circuit was born. The sensor was added to ensure that the circuit only ever worked while a rod was securly seated in position, and the 555 timer, (continued)

Comment: (continued), was intended to activate the solenoid for just enough time for the rod to be injected, while ensuring it was pressed for long enough to fully inject it. The short pulse length sent from the 555 would also prevent a sensor or circuit failure from keeping the solenoid on, thus preventing another solenoid meltdown. The sensor was implemented easily and the idea for this circuit was to simply cut the power using the relay, so that when the button was pressed and the sensor detected a fully seated rod it would inject.   (continued)

Comment: @Pizzashape23 awesome! Could you really **edit** your question to include that? (it's a wee bit easier to find for readers that way)

Comment: (continued). The sensor circuit is already very simple, and by cutting the power i could control all the solenoids at once without much integration. (with the sensor, it would only activate those with a rod in place). The main failure states to be conserned with would be a jam, a blocked sensor, and a false trigger, all things the timer circuit would solve. My hesitance to give away details in highsight was very stupid, how could you help without knowing everything, however I am not in charge of this project so they weren't my details to give away. Again very sorry, but now you know everything

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Do you think I could get your opinion on whether it would work or not, now that you know the whole story?

Comment: Pizzashape, do you think you could heed my repeated request to include all the necessary info in your question by **editing** it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Sorry I completely forgot, I have been very busy the last couple of days.  Would you be able to post a response after the question has been edited?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, The post has been edited to explain what I told you in the comments, again sorry about the initial confusion.